# Get Specific Column data using mysqli_result()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function which authenticates user for login.

```
$login_query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],
"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as `count`,`user_id` FROM `users`
     WHERE `user_email`='$email' AND `user_password` = '" . md5($password) . "'") or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['conn']));
return ($mysqli_result->num_rows == 1) ? 
           mysqli_result($login_query, 0, 'user_id') : false;
```

I was using `mysql_*` and now switching to `mysqli_*`.

What I want to know is that, in `return` statement how do I return `user_id` from the row that has been selected from DB?

Comment: You shouldn't simply swap mysql_* functions to mysqli_* ones. You better should use prepared statements with placeholders and bind your input values to those placeholders to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @VMai PDO is also good, but I am asking something else

Comment: I commented on what you're doing, I didn't gave you an answer. The [mysqli_result class](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) has got methods ... By the way I won't recommend the use of MD5 either, but it's slightly better than plaintext passwords.

Comment: Does this work for you? `return ($mysqli_result->num_rows == 1)? $mysqli_result->fetch_assoc()['user_id']: false;`

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the query a little. This function will return the user_id if the login is successful or "0" if not.

Make the $mysqli connection in a config file that you can include at the top of each page

```
#config.php#

$dbhost =   "localhost";
$dbuser =   "";
$dbpassword =   "";
$dbdatabase =   "";
$salt       =       "";
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbdatabase);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo '<p>There was a problem with the mysqli connection: 
           <br>&emsp;'.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';
    exit;
}   

   #Calling the function:#
   require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
   checklogin($email, $password, $salt, $mysqli);


   function checklogin($email, $password, $salt="", $mysqli)
   {

    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

    $login_query = '
                SELECT * 
                FROM 
                       `users`
                WHERE 
                       `user_email`='$email' 
                AND 
                       `user_password` = "' . md5($salt.$password) . '";';

    $result = $mysqli->query($login_query)
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {$user_id = $row['user_id'];}
    else
    {$user_id = 0;}

    return $user_ID

    }
```